# how to calculate the sum of two fields in Django model?

Tags: django-models

## store value (a + b) in the c field

class R(models.Model):

```
a = models.IntegerField(null=True)
b = models.IntegerField(null=True)
c = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Comment: This is *not* a question. You should explain *what* you aim to do, what you tried, and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise *not* to store the sum in a field. Since `c` simply depends on `a` and `b`, we can use a property that calculates this on demand. For example:

```
lass R(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    b = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    @property
    def c(self):
        if self.a is not None and self.b is not None:
            return self.a + self.b
```

You can also annotate a `QuerySet` and filter the `QuerySet` based on the sum, for example:

```
from django.db.models import F

R.objects.annotate(
    my_c=F('a')+F('b')
).filter(my_c__gt=10)
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), we can work with [**`.alias(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) instead:

```
from django.db.models import F

R.objects.alias(
    my_c=F('a')+F('b')
).filter(my_c__gt=10)
```

Comment: so that how can i store the summation value in a another field in the same model?

Comment: @Md.RedoneHassan: you should not do this, since this is *data duplication*, and it turns out that even on the same database, keeping values in sync is a hard problem.

Comment: so how to solve this type of problem? Have any approach?

Comment: @Md.RedoneHassan: use a *property*, not a *database field*.

Comment: ok. then how can i use properties return value and store this value in database?

Comment: @Md.RedoneHassan: you should *not* store the value in the database. By creating an extra field, you introduce data duplication, if a value depends entirely on the value of two other values, it makes no sense to store something functionally dependent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_3NF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232944/discussion-between-md-redone-hassan-and-willem-van-onsem).